# web service update error

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

i have a web service that show me this error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0', date_de_naissance = '1988-02-02', lieu_de_naissance = ' at line 4{"items":[["succes"]]}

```
<?php

include('settings.php');
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($base);

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$id_patient = $_GET['id_patient'];

$nom = $_GET['nom'];
$prenom = $_GET['prenom'];
$Sexe = $_GET['Sexe'];
$date_de_naissance = $_GET['date_de_naissance'];
$lieu_de_naissance = $_GET['lieu_de_naissance'];

$adresse = $_GET['adresse'];
$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
$longitude = $_GET['longitude'];
$telephone = $_GET['telephone'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

$situation_familiale = $_GET['situation_familiale'];
$profession = $_GET['profession'];
$numero_securite_sociale = $_GET['numero_securite_sociale'];
$taille = $_GET['taille'];
$poids = $_GET['poids'];


$groupe_sanguin = $_GET['groupe_sanguin'];
$allergies = $_GET['allergies'];
$antecedents_chirurgicaux = $_GET['antecedents_chirurgicaux'];
$antecedents_medicaux = $_GET['antecedents_medicaux'];
$antecedents_familiaux = $_GET['antecedents_familiaux'];

if ($id_patient!= NULL )
{

$req = "UPDATE patient SET nom = '".$nom."' , prenom = '".$prenom.", Sexe =    '".$Sexe."',
     date_de_naissance = '".$date_de_naissance."',

     lieu_de_naissance = '".$lieu_de_naissance."',

     adresse = '".$adresse."',
     latitude =  '".$latitude."',
     longitude =  '".$longitude."',
     telephone =   '".$telephone."',
     email =   '".$email."',

     situation_familiale =  '".$situation_familiale."',
     profession =  '".$profession."',
     numero_securite_sociale =  '".$numero_securite_sociale."',
    taille =  '".$taille."',
     poids =  '".$poids."',


     groupe_sanguin =  '".$groupe_sanguin."',
     allergies =  '".$allergies."',
     antecedents_chirurgicaux = '".$antecedents_chirurgicaux."',
     antecedents_medicaux =  '".$antecedents_medicaux."',
     antecedents_familiaux = '".$antecedents_familiaux."'


         WHERE id_patient = '".$id_patient."'   ";

$sql=mysql_query($req);
echo mysql_error();
$items = array("items" => NULL);
$items["items"][] = array("succes");
echo json_encode($items,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
else{$items = array("items" => NULL);
$items["items"][] = array("erreur");
echo json_encode($items,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);}

?>
```

Comment: i see a missing single quote, can you spot it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

A closing quote was missing.

```
$req = "UPDATE patient SET nom = '".$nom."' , prenom = '".$prenom."', Sexe = '".$Sexe."',
```